# How is it that the cross product of two vectors is always perpendicular to the given vectors?

Tags: vectors

Vector addition, subtraction and dot product seem logical enough, but I don't understand how two vectors acting on the same plane maybe, can give a perpendicular resultant.

Comment: If you embed a plane in a three dimensional space, you can characterize it by its normal i.e. the vector that is everywhere perpendicular to the plane. Since a plane is constructed out of two non collinear vectors, it means that you can virtually construct an operation that from two vectors will give you a third one perpendicular to them.

Comment: By definition of cross product.

Comment: This should be asked in [Mathematics.SE].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think of it this way: it takes exactly two vectors to define a plane. But a plane has a different set of symmetries than a vector does. If you have to shoehorn information about a plane into a vector, the closest thing to a *unique* vector is one normal to the surface. It so happens that the cross product is a relatively simple operation which produces this normal.

Answer (score 0):

Well, assume a ball goes on a ring. You need some definition for angular variables like angular velocity, angular momentum etc. But this variables are constant if there is no torque applied to the ball. So, these variables are assumed to be constant in vector representation and this requires that these vectors should be perpendicular to the ring surface.

Actually, I am seeing vector product just a method or convention to produce these vectors.